# Guzzle get result on pool

Tags: php, guzzle6

I am using Guzzle Async pool, however it seems that the documentation is missing part in how can I use the pool to fetch the returns?

As per the documentation:

```
$client = new Client();

$requests = function ($total) use ($client) {
    $uri = 'http://localhost/';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        yield function() use ($client, $uri) {
            return $client->requestAsync($uri);
        };
    }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(100));
```

How can I use the `$pool` to consume all the reply?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pool::batch()` method for that. Also consider to limit concurrency to avoid firing 100 requests at once...

```
$responses = Pool::batch(
    $client,
    $requests(100),
    ['concurrency' => 5]
);
```